# Discord.js bot getting a Bitfield Invalid error after changing intent

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

Had another post about my bot running in the terminal, but not posting a message in the discord channel.  I changed the intents because I cam across a different question where someone needed to change the intents so that the bot would post in Discord.. After I made the change to intents I am now getting this error:
RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.message, Intents.channel, Intents.reaction] });


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`It's welcome time`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'Hi') {
    msg.reply('Welcome wallet warrior!');
    msg.channel.send('Welcome wallet warrior!');

  }
  else {
    msg.channel.send('Hi, please introduce yourself')
  };

});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Intents.message` `Intents.channel` `Intents.reaction` is undefined, or has no value.

The right Intents you probably need:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
     intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
     ]
});
```

There is a [discord.js official guide](https://discordjs.guide) that might help you.

Comment: If you find yourself posting the same answer to multiple questions, you should consider using the *Flag* option under the post and mark posts as a duplicate of a question that already has the right answer.

Comment: okay, i'm new to stack overflow lol

Comment: OKay I am also new haha.. I was told to ask a post a different question from my previous post.